# javascript code inside php in wordpress function.php file

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, themes

hello everyone I have a question regarding a piece of Javascript code inside php in the wordpress theme in the function.php file. The code is this:

```
if (is_page ('8434-2')) { 
    ?>             -->end php??
        <script type="text/javascript">   ---->start javascript code
          function submitBAI(event){
           var fianchi= document.getElementById("BAI-fianchi").value /100;
           var altezza= document.getElementById("BAI-altezza").value /100;
           var BAI = Math.round(100*(fianchi/(Math.sqrt(altezza)*Math.sqrt(altezza)*Math.sqrt(altezza)))-18);
           log.textContent= "Il tuo BAI = " + BAI +" %";
           event.preventDefault();
          }
          const form = document.getElementById("BAI-form");
          const log = document.getElementById("logBAI");
          form.addEventListener("submit", submitBAI);
        </script>    -->end javascript code
    <?php     -->start new php code
  }
```

what does this piece of code mean?
After the declaration of the is_page('8434-2') function, WordPress insert some javascript code, but there is the symbol ?>, which indicates the end of the php code, why? It should not be:

```
if (is_page ('8434-2')) { 
<php
<script type="text/javascript"> do something</script>
?>
}
```

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript">` isn't PHP code so it would throw an error if it was inside a PHP block. https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `?>` token here means stopping of PHP code interpretation, and start echoing/printing the content as-is. The `<?php` then ends the echoing/printing and revert back to PHP code intepretation.